# Why is my result varying if I am performing division with a macro vs local variable?

Tags: c, gcc

I have been working on a C code. I have declared few constants using #define. However I have observed that while I am performing division of a local  variable with a constant(defined using #define) I am numerically getting a wrong answer.

I have tried changing the constant defined(using #define) to a local variable and then performing division. Now I am getting correct answer.

The problem is I have many constants, whose values are to be used throughout various functions. I want to know how I can solve this problem.

These are the results I am getting when used #define
"0.106883 is q2, 11.575652 is D2 ,0.000004 is q2/D2"

These are the results I am getting when used as a local variable.
"0.106883 is q2, 11.575652 is D2 ,0.009233 is q2/D2"

I am using GCC 8.3.0_2. This is a simpler version of my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define D2 (h2()*2)/(50)
double h2(void);

int main(){
 double q2 = 0.106883;
 printf("%f is q2, %f is D2 ,%f is q2/D2\n",q2,D2,q2/D2);

}
double h2(void){
 return(289.391293);
}
```

Comment: Let's see the actual code.

Comment: What type(s) are the variables?  How have you determined these values?

Comment: @ScottHunter q2 is double, D2 is the constant(when declared as a local variable I used double) I am talking about.

Comment: @MatteoItalia The actual code is 500 lines big. Let me see if I could replicate the error using a small code.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I have attached a simpler version of my problem.

Comment: @Tyrion I think you meant to do this in your code `printf("%f is q2, %f is D2, %f is q2/D2, %f\n", q2, D2, q2/D2, q2/((h2()*2)/(50)));`, in order to express your question.. That should also hint you for the answer! :)  Παρενθέσεις.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `#define` your expression is actually `q2/(h2()*2)/50`, not `q2/((h2()*2)/50)`. You need to wrap your `#define` in parentheses, i.e. `#define D2 ((h2()*2)/50)`

Macros are basically just textual replacement. As another example:

```
#define a 1+2
int b = 3*a   // 3*1+2 = 5
int c = 3*(a) // 3*(1+2) = 9
```